# JSON Schema: Allow multiple types in array while specifying the order and amount of the types

Tags: json, jsonschema

I understand that this kind of JSON structure isn't very good, but this is merely for myself for convenience while still verifying that what I create is valid.

The goal JSON files that **SHOULD** validate are the following;

```json
[
  [ "string1" ]
]
```

```json
[
  [ "string1", true ]
]
```

```json
[
  [ "string1", true, "string2" ]
]
```

Each of these *inner* arrays **MAY** additionally contain *another* array as the final item. Said array will simply have the same validation as the root array (`"$ref": "#"`). There **MUST** be at least 1 item in the root array.

This means that these JSON files **SHOULD NOT** validate;

```json
[

]
```

```json
[
  [ "string1", [] ]
]
```

Declaring which types are allowed in the array items is fairly easy in a schema file, and I've done so right here;

```json
{
  "title": "",
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 1,
  "items": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": [ "string", "boolean", "array" ],
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "$ref": "#"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this obviously does not validate the exact order and amount of the types. Is something like that even possible with something like the `oneOf` property? Maybe some combination of `if` and `then`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're headed the right direction.  You have the basic structure, but there are a few redundancies I'd like to point out.

```json
{
  "title": "",
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 1,
  "items": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": [ "string", "boolean", "array" ], // [1]
      "anyOf": [ // [2]
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        {
          "type": "array", // [3]
          "$ref": "#"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

1. This is just specifying the same as the `oneOf`.  It's not adding any extra validation and can be removed.
2. `anyOf` isn't going to help with specifying order.  This will allow these elements in any order.  More on how to ensure order below.
3. Since the target of the `$ref` (the root) already declares `type`, this is unnecessary and can be removed.

Also, I'm not sure what version of JSON Schema you're using.  The keywords I tell you to use will depend on this.  I'll answer with draft 2020-12 keywords.

#### Item order

If you know the length of the inner array, you can use the `prefixItems` keyword to specify each item in an index-based fashion.  Then `items` will address any other items.

```json
{
  "type": "array",
  "prefixItems": [
    { "type": "boolean" },
    { "type": "string" },
    { "type": "boolean" }
  ],
  "items": { "type": "integer" }
}
```

This schema will require a boolean, then a string, then a boolean, and then any number of integers.  These are all valid:

```json
[ true, "string", false, 1, 3, 5 ]
[ true, "string" ]
[ true, "string", false ]
```

These are invalid:

```json
[ true, "string", 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Note that `prefixItems` doesn't require that there are three items, just that the items that *are* there match those subschemas.

Unfortunately, there's not a way to specify a schema for the *last* item.  So if the array can be any length, then you're a bit out of luck.

#### A verbose option

If you don't know how many items you're going have, but you know there's an upper limit, you can do something like this:

```json
{
  "title": "",
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 1,
  "items": {
    "type": "array",
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "prefixItems": [
          { "type": "string" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "prefixItems": [
          { "type": "string" },
          { "type": "boolean" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "prefixItems": [
          { "type": "string" },
          { "type": "boolean" },
          { "type": "string" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "unevaluatedItems": { "$ref": "#" }
  }
}
```

The `anyOf` subschemas build up the options one item at a time.  You only have to match against one of them, then `unevaluatedItems` operates like `items` from above (there's a technical reason you need the different keyword, but that's a blog post worth of explanation).

This will validate all of the ones you have in your question and these:

```json
[ "string", [ ["string"] ] ]
[ "string", false, [ ["string"] ] ]
[ "string", false, "string", [ ["string"] ] ]
```

Comment: Wow, very thorough answer! Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!